# print a function by default in Python 2.7.11?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The other day I accidentally wrote

```
print("a function?")
```

in my Python 2.7.11 console and was quiet astonished that it would work instead of throwing an error. I assumed, there was an implicit

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and tried

```
print "also a statement???"
```

which also worked! Note that, when importing from `__future__` the statement is disabled. It *is* in fact disabled, and only the function sytax works if I import `print_function`

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print) still read:

```
Note: This function is not normally available as a built-in since the 
name print is recognized as the print statement. To disable the 
statement and use the print() function, use this future statement at 
the top of your module: (...)
```

What did I miss? Why is `print` a statement *and* a builtin function in Python 2.7?

Comment: `("a function?")` is just the string `"a function?"` with brackets around it. You're just putting unnecessary brackets around your argument to the `print` statement.

Comment: print is actually a special statement, not a function.

Comment: I stumble upon this once in a while... I will never get used to the triple meaning of parentheses O_o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the string "a function?" is an expression in Python, and an expression in parentheses is also an expression.

So your command was `print ("a function?")`, just printing an expression.

That is convenient for writing a line that works in both Python 2.x and in Python 3.x. The book "Python Crash Course" uses this to show code that works in both versions of Python.